# In ruby, how could I trigger a program when redis is not empy?

Tags: ruby, redis, producer-consumer

I use redis list as a queue, i also have a consumer program take the stuff from redis. I want to have the consumer in ruby take stuff from redis as long as redis is not empty. Do you know how could i achieve this? Right now, I manually run the consumer program.

Comment: Have you had a look at the [`BRPOP`](http://redis.io/commands/BRPOP) command? Jam that into a loop.

Comment: Why are you trying to use Redis as a message broker? Why not use a real message broker?